# Rotate the icon by 180 degrees

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin iOS development, and I've tried to rotate the icon by 180 degrees when tapped.
I write the following method for the rotation.

```
private void titleViewTapped(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
    {
        var rotationAnimation = new CoreAnimation.CABasicAnimation();
        rotationAnimation.KeyPath = "transform.rotation.z";
        rotationAnimation.To = new NSNumber(Math.PI);
        rotationAnimation.Duration = 0.2;
        rotationAnimation.RemovedOnCompletion = false;
        rotationAnimation.FillMode = CoreAnimation.CAFillMode.Forwards;

        triangleIcon.Layer.AddAnimation(rotationAnimation, "rotationAnimation");
    }
```

The program works well when I tapped the title for the first time.
However, when I tapped the title again, the icon was rotated by 360 degrees, not 180.
How to solve this issue?

---

I've solved this issue by myself.

```
private void titleViewTapped(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
    {
        UIView.Animate(0.2,
            () => {
                triangleIcon.Transform = CGAffineTransform.Rotate(triangleIcon.Transform, (nfloat)Math.PI);},
            () => { }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  - (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration rotations:(CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The `repeatCount `  should not be used because I don't want to repeat the rotation, just when tapped

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by myself.

```
private void titleViewTapped(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
    {
        UIView.Animate(0.2,
            () => {
                triangleIcon.Transform = CGAffineTransform.Rotate(triangleIcon.Transform, (nfloat)Math.PI);},
            () => { }
        );
    }
```